# Moving from php5.2.17 to 5.3.3

Tags: php, centos, centos6, centos5

I am moving a server from Centos 5 php5.2.17 to Centos 6 php5.3.3
I am facing up a problem with a code I didn’t wrote. There’s no problem in the old server for around two years but in the new one, tests warn me:
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in path_to_template/template.php on line 43

Searching **recursively**:
template.php ->line 43:

```
while($value_comment = mysql_fetch_array($result_comments))
```

---

```
$result_comments = getComments($unique_id);
```

---

```
function getComments($unique_id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM (...)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    return $result;
}
```

---

```
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db = mysql_select_db($db,$link);`

$host “…”;
$username = “…”;
$password = “…”;
$db = “…”;`
```

To get an output error I changed $result: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

*No database selected*

I don’t realize what has changed between both php versions

**Found the solution**
mysql username was imported but without privileges on any database (automatic things...!)

Comment: mysql_functions.. take cover.

Comment: may be some of the code is not executing due to short-tags being disabled in the new version???

Comment: You're probably going to receive a lot of explanation about why you should use mysqli_query instead. Aside from the security aspects, Also mysql_query is due to be depreciated as of 5.5

Comment: I use a lot of mysql_query function in other scripts and they all work fine

Comment: Short tags are on, if not, all php code would be displayed in browsers

Comment: This doesn't have to do with your problem, but you should think about updating to php 5.5 or 5.6 straight. Php 5.3 is EOL, which means, that there won't be any security updates for this version anymore. As you have to migrate the code from php 5.2 anyways, you might as well skip 5.3-5.5, have your code running on 5.6 and be safe until at least 08/2017 (that's when php 5.6 will become EOL).

Comment: @Pierre I use webmin/virtualmin control panel and its repositories.
Centos6 package come with that php version, it is supposed to be the last 'secure' & verified

Answer (score 0):

maybe your old server php error reporting is switched off.
You recive this error, when the mysql returns 0 records.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numResults = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numResults > 0) {
    // mysql_fetch_array
}
```

Comment: This is not about error reporting! It is about working scripts! The old one displays data taken from database, the new one does not. Same scripts

Comment: Please try this: var_dump($result); What is your result?